# How to access Filter values in Crossfilter

Tags: d3.js, crossfilter

I know how to alter filters in Crossfilter using:

javascript:filter([null, [80, 150], null, [new Date(fromDate), new Date(toDate)]])

But how do I get the current filter selection e.g. when a user selects a range using the slider. I need it to pass back to my calendar JS object.

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you using brush concepts in sliders... If so you can get the filter range as brush.extent ...